# How to solve this error 'JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject'

Tags: php, android, json

I know there are few similar threads but none of them really help. I'm trying to parse PHP foreach loop to Json and then to Android. There is a list of URLs addresses where apk files can be downloaded and that is what I'm looping through.
This is the error that I'm faced with every time I run the program.

```
Error :- org.json.JSONException: Value ["xxxx.apk"] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

PHP code:

```
$fileList = glob('xxxx/xxx/appstore_php/*');
   foreach($fileList as $filename)
   {
      if ( is_file ( $filename ) )
      {
         $bname = basename ( $filename);
         $b = array($bname);    
         echo json_encode($b);
      }
   }
```

Output :- ["xxxx.apk"]["xxy.apk"]
Android code:

```
  private void getAppData(){
        //Creating a string request
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(URLAddress.SHOW_ALL_APK,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    JSONObject j = null;
                    try {
                        //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                        j = new JSONObject(response);

                        //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                        result = j.getJSONArray(URLAddress.JSON_ARRAY);

                        getApps(result);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            });

        //Creating a request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void getApps(JSONArray j){
        //Traversing through all the items in the json array
        for(int i=0;i<j.length();i++){
            try {
                //Getting json object
                JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);
                appList.add( json.toString() );

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure this is [tag:php]? Looks to be more like a c based language? The majority of this is **NOT** php syntax

Comment: Why not just change `j = new JSONObject(response);` to `j = new JSONArray(response);`?

Comment: I can assure you it's PHP.

Comment: I think it's Java. Just like the error is telling you, json array is not a json object. Just like in javascript, square bracket indicates an array, curly braces indicate an object

Comment: could you please add the json string you are getting as a response from the server? the response object you receive in the ResponseListener.onResponse method in android.

Comment: What are your trying to achieve with this ?  
result = j.getJSONArray(URLAddress.JSON_ARRAY); 
and where are you defining 'result' as a jsonarray ?

Comment: I have a seperate class
public class URLAddress {

    //JSON URL
    public static final String LOGIN = "http://xxx/xxx/login.php";
    public static final String SHOW_ALL_APK = "http://xxx/xxx/show_all_apk.php";
    
    //JSON array name
    public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
}

Comment: pass your response directly to the getApps() method. Do not convert to Jsonobject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form chat discussion, response return to `{"files": ["xxxx.apk","xxy.apk"]}` format

```
   $fileList = glob('xxxx/xxx/appstore_php/*');
   $files = [];
   foreach($fileList as $filename)
   {
      if ( is_file ( $filename ) )
      {
         $bname = basename ( $filename);
         $files[] = $bname;  
      }
   }

   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   $response = ["files" => $files]; //later you can add extra in it too
   echo json_encode($response);
```

Here the output should be like this

```
{"files": ["xxxx.apk","xxy.apk"]}
```

Comment: This is what I'm getting now ;-  Value ["xxxx.apk","xxy.apk"] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: can you try `JSONArray  j = new JSONArray(response);` because `Value ["xxxx.apk","xxy.apk"]` this an array

Comment: It crashed on me

Comment: let your Android code as it is and add `header('Content-Type: application/json');` in php side. i have updated the answer

Comment: @Tony document says `JSONArray` should be used  if response start with array brackets. means '['

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173493/discussion-between-rkj-and-tony).